# VS Initialize Flexible Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am very new to C++ and sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to figure out why I am struggling to add values to a simple array of integers. When I ctrl+f5 to print to screen, I receive '0000'. I would think it would print 0,1,2,3,4?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


#define NUM_PINS    5

int controllers[NUM_PINS];

void main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PINS; i++) {
        std::cout << controllers[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `controllers` is not explicitly initialized. Since it's global, its elements will be initialized to 0. Also you're not printing any commas, so I don't know why you would expect the output to contain commas.

Comment: Since you never assign any values to the array, and global variables are initialized to their default, why would you expect different results than what you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing controllers[i] (each index) to anything. Below is a way of initilizing it to 0 1 2 3 4 and printing it out. If this is your desired goal.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


#define NUM_PINS    5

int controllers[NUM_PINS];

void main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PINS; i++) {
        controllers[i] = i;
        std::cout << controllers[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I normally use Python which isn't a very strict language (so permits bad expectations). Thanks and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @ErikSvenBroberg glad you learned, and you came to the right website to get help!